# Java printing InternalError actual error

Tags: java, error-handling

Within the code I am hitting an InternalError.  I want to be able to print out the actual error.

The actual error is however is far down the stack.  The actual error is

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout"`

```
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.InternalError: Should not reach 
here
at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunneling(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunnel(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl$2.run(Unknown Source)

....

at checker.ui.panels.SystemCheckPanel.run(SystemCheckPanel.java:1058)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout"
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(Unknown Source)
... 19 more'
```

How do i print the actual error being 504 Message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 try {
    blah...
 } catch (IOException e) {
     Throwable cause = e.getCause();
     System.out.println(cause.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: The source code was not code, but an exception stack.  The goal was to figure out how to print the cause by's.